# Adding labels to sides in a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I am just getting the hang of tikz, I have the below code for a proof of the Pythagorean theorem

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.50]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,10) -- (13,7) -- (10,-3) -- cycle ;
\draw (3,7) -- (13,7) ;
\draw (3,7) -- (3,10) ;
\draw (10,7) -- (10,-3) ;
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) ;
\draw (3,0) -- (3,10) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it produces the following figure
[image]

What I need is the following
[image]

I am new to tikz and Latex in general, so I need help. Is there a way to add the side labels for the right triangle as in the labeled figure? I thank all helpers.

Comment: Text is added via nodes.  While the default is to center the text at a given coordinate, you can use options like [abore] [left] [below right] to move them to the side.  The default distance is given by [inner sep=0.333em], but you can increase the distance using [above=5pt] (for example).

Comment: You can also add nodes along paths using options like [midway] [pos=0.5] and [sloped].

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you very much. Could you please provide an example since I am still learning?

Comment: TikZ comes with an overly complete manual including lots of tutorials.  You can download it from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) and a copy may already be in your system.  For MikTeX, you will need to install pgf__doc to get ragular updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.50]
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left](){c}(3,10) -- (13,7) -- (10,-3) -- cycle ;
    \draw (3,7) -- (13,7) ;
    \draw (3,7) -- (3,10) ;
    \draw (10,7) -- (10,-3) ;
    \draw (0,0) -- node[above, pos=0.2](){b}(10,0) ;
    \draw (3,0) -- node[right](){a}(3,10) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**To understand further**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.50]
    \draw (0,0) -- node[above, pos=1]{c}(3,10) -- (13,7) -- (10,-3) -- cycle ;
    \draw (3,7) -- (13,7) ;
    \draw (3,7) -- (3,10) ;
    \draw (10,7) -- (10,-3) ;
    \draw (0,0) -- node[above, pos=0.5]{b}(10,0) ;
    \draw (3,0) -- node[right=1cm, red, thick, circle, draw]{a}(3,10) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Could you please tell me why we need the () after the square brackets in the nodes?

Comment: its included by habit -- you can remove () -- these are used for naming the nodes for referencing later on

Comment: thank you very much I am still trying to learn. What exactly does node mean? Does it refer to the point or line? Because it seems the labels a b c aren't adjacent to points but to lines.

Comment: `node`= an arbitrary point with some inner padding/ thickness, can be placed anywhere using options in square brackets, including color, shapes etc -- more in the documentation -- search google -- `ctan pgf`

Answer (score 1):

Even you are new to TikZ, but in fact your question is already answered in some answers of your previous questions. For the manual and a minimal introduction to TikZ, see [this](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en).

Here is a way that you can control numbers `a`, `b` via `[declare function]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={midway,magenta},join=round,
declare function={a=3;b=1;c=sqrt(a*a+b*b);}]

\draw (0,0)
--(0,a)  node[right]{$a$}
--(-b,0) node[left]{$c$}
--cycle  node[above]{$b$};
\draw
(a-b,0)--(a-b,-b)--(-b,0)--cycle
(a-b,a-b)--(a-b,-b)--(a,a-b)--cycle
(0,a-b)--(0,a)--(a,a-b)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `quotes` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
\draw (0,0) to ["$c$"] (3,10) -- (13,7) -- (10,-3) -- cycle ;
\draw (3,7) -- (13,7) ;
\draw (3,7) -- (3,10) ;
\draw (10,7) -- (10,-3);
\draw (0,0) to ["$b$"] (3,0) -- (10,0) ;
\draw (3,0) to ["$a$"]  (3,10) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```